# Joomla removes img tags from HTML of modules loaded in article content

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, content-filtering, joomla3.8

Somehow, Joomla removes `img` tags from the HTML code of modules loaded in article content by `{loadmodule}` or [Modules Anywhere](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/modulesanywhere) and I can't find a way to stop it.

I have a Joomla 3.8.2 site where there is a module called Bootstap Tabs which simply shows articles in tabs so each tab is one article. Each of these articles is used to load a single module using `{loadmodule}`. That module is of type [Articles Newsflash Advanced](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/tm_art_news_adv/) 1.5.6 (`mod_articles_news_adv`) and simply shows some fixed number of titles and intro texts from articles from given category. It should also show intro images. When I use Articles Newsflash Advanced modules in a standard way, everything works fine. But in this multiple-inculsion way `img` tags are stripped away. And I mean that they are stripped away regardless of where are they placed in the HTML code of the override.

So, in short:

- OK: module shows list of articles with `img`s;
- Error: module shows article that loads another module which shows list of articles - `img` tags are stripped away.

What I tried to do:

- I tried to put `img` tags in the strangest places in HTML override of `mod_articles_news_adv` to find what exactly is being filtered - and it seems that it's all of module's HTML code;
- I tried to use some alternative to `{loadmodule}`, I used [Modules Anywhere](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/modulesanywhere) but problem remained.

EDIT:
There is some [related question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/18496/how-to-show-images-in-intro-text-section-on-article-news-flash-advanced-gallery) in Joomla SE, looks like the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `Bootstap Tabs` was stripping images. In the `Item Settings` tab of this module there is `Show Content Images` setting and it was set to `No` while it should be set to `Yes`.